# How upgrade proj to 6.1 in OSGeo4W?

Tags: windows, proj, osgeo

I wish to use the python library **keplergl**.
This library use the library **proj**
How to reported on [proj site home](https://proj.org/install.html), to install proj on Windows i must use OSGeo4W.
but there is a problem, keplergl requirs proj 6.1:

```
ERROR: Minimum supported proj version is 6.1.0, installed version is 5.2.0.
```

and OSGeo4W has in his packet proj 5.

How can I upgrade proj to 6.1?

Thanks